# Problems at require(<Module>) in self written Node-RED node

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, node-red

I added a self written WebSocket-Client library. When I `require` in node.js it works fine, just as in Node-RED's function-node with registering it in `settings.js` and requireing it by `global.get("RWSjs")`.

Now I had to write a Node by myself and wanted to require this file, and it doesn't work. Node-RED always gives me the "node not deployed" error, which is, I think, because of a javascript syntax error.

How can I require a self written module in a self written node's .js?

Thanks a lot in advance, Peter :)

*Edit:*

some Code:

eval-R-char.js (Code for the node)

```
module.exports = function(RED) {               

    // doesn't work:
    var RWSjs = global.get("RWSjs");

    function EvalRCharNode(config) {            
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);      

        this.instruction = config.instruction;
        var node = this;
        this.on('input', function(msg) {        
            //msg.payload = msg.payload.toLowerCase();
            msg.payload = "Instruction: " + this.instruction;
            node.send(msg);                     
        });                                     
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("eval-R-char",EvalRCharNode); 
}
```

Comment: Your going to have to share some code and node-red console output if you want us to help. Also how/where have you deployed your "self written module"

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post the code, I added it to the question. The flow now consists of an inject and a debug output. I testes the node without "requiring" my RWSjs file, and the tests worked, it gave the intended test output `Instruction: print(hello)`. When I added the `global.get` line the "node not deployed" error came. I deployed my module by editing Node-RED's `settings.js` at `functionGlobalContext`. I added a line `RWSjs:require('./jsModules/RWSjs.js')`; in the function node it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the context to `require` modules when writing your own nodes, it is purely a workaround as you can't use `require` in the function node.

You should just `require` as normal in your custom node.

So in this case:

```
module.exports = function(RED) {               

    //assuming your module is in the RWS.js file in the same directory
    var RWSjs = require('./RWS.js');

    function EvalRCharNode(config) {            
        RED.nodes.createNode(this,config);      

        this.instruction = config.instruction;
        var node = this;
        this.on('input', function(msg) {        
            //msg.payload = msg.payload.toLowerCase();
            msg.payload = "Instruction: " + this.instruction;
            node.send(msg);                     
        });                                     
    }
    RED.nodes.registerType("eval-R-char",EvalRCharNode); 
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see - I thought this sandbox restriction of the function node was also valid in custom nodes - thank you very much!